# How to configure row/column sizes in grid managed frames in a python tkinter class project

Tags: python, class, tkinter, grid

I am creating a GUI in python using Tkinter and classes and having trouble resizing specific rows in the grid packager.

The code I have attached works but I would like to control the row widths so that the top 2 frames are static in size and the bottom resizes with the window.  I have tried many things whilst referencing different solutions but nothing works.

```
# !/usr/bin/python3

# Use Tkinter for python 2, tkinter for python 3
import tkinter as tk

# Main Window
class WinMain(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        # parameters that you want to send through the Frame class. 
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        # reference to the master widget, which is the tk window
        self.master = master

        # with that, we want to then run init_window, which doesn't yet exist
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        # changing the title of our master widget      
        self.master.title("GUI Tester")

        # Create menu for window
        self.createMenu()

        # Create Gui for window
        self.createGui()

        # Update Gui every second after 1 second
        self.after(1000, self.upDateGui)

    def createMenu(self):
        # Initialise drop-down menu
        menu = tk.Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        # Add drop-down menu for Options
        options = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=False)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=options)
        options.add_command(label="Open...", command=self.menuOptionsOpen)
        options.add_separator()
        options.add_command(label="Close", command=self.menuOptionsClose)

        # Add drop-down menu for Help
        help = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=False)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=help)
        help.add_command(label="About...", command=self.menuHelpAbout)

    def createGui(self):
        # Define GUI using Grid to place widgets
        # Size window to its minimum set to 2/3 of the screen resolution
        top = self.winfo_toplevel()

        screen_width = top.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = top.winfo_screenheight()
        screen_resolution = str(int(screen_width * 2 / 3)) + 'x' + str(int(screen_height * 2 / 3))

        top.geometry(screen_resolution)
        top.minsize(int(screen_width * 1 / 3), int(screen_height * 1 / 3))

        # ------------------------------------------------
        # create all frames
        # ------------------------------------------------
        self.c = self.master
        self.c.frameTop = tk.LabelFrame(self.c, text="Top", width=5, height=5, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.c.frameMiddle = tk.LabelFrame(self.c, text="Middle", width=5, height=5, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.c.frameBottom = tk.LabelFrame(self.c, text="Bottom", width=5, height=5, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.c.frameRight = tk.Frame(self.c, borderwidth=5, relief=tk.GROOVE)

        # ------------------------------------------------
        # Create widgets for frameTop
        # ------------------------------------------------
        # Text Box
        self.c.frameTop.textBox = tk.Text(self.c.frameTop, borderwidth=3, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
        self.c.frameTop.textBox.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='none')

        # Text Box Scroll Bars
        self.c.frameTop.textBoxYScroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.c.frameTop, orient=tk.VERTICAL,
                                                      command=self.c.frameTop.textBox.yview)
        self.c.frameTop.textBox['yscrollcommand'] = self.c.frameTop.textBoxYScroll.set

        self.c.frameTop.textBoxXScroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.c.frameTop, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                                                      command=self.c.frameTop.textBox.xview)
        self.c.frameTop.textBox['xscrollcommand'] = self.c.frameTop.textBoxXScroll.set
        # ------------------------------------------------
        # Create widgets for frameMiddle
        # ------------------------------------------------
        # Text Box
        self.c.frameMiddle.textBox = tk.Text(self.c.frameMiddle, borderwidth=3, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
        self.c.frameMiddle.textBox.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='none')

        # Text Box Scroll Bars
        self.c.frameMiddle.textBoxYScroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.c.frameMiddle, orient=tk.VERTICAL,
                                                         command=self.c.frameMiddle.textBox.yview)
        self.c.frameMiddle.textBox['yscrollcommand'] = self.c.frameMiddle.textBoxYScroll.set

        self.c.frameMiddle.textBoxXScroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.c.frameMiddle, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                                                         command=self.c.frameMiddle.textBox.xview)
        self.c.frameMiddle.textBox['xscrollcommand'] = self.c.frameMiddle.textBoxXScroll.set
        # ------------------------------------------------
        # Create widgets for frameBottom
        # ------------------------------------------------
        # Text Box
        self.c.frameBottom.textBox = tk.Text(self.c.frameBottom, borderwidth=3, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
        self.c.frameBottom.textBox.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='none')

        # Text Box Scroll Bars
        self.c.frameBottom.textBoxYScroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.c.frameBottom, orient=tk.VERTICAL,
                                                         command=self.c.frameBottom.textBox.yview)
        self.c.frameBottom.textBox['yscrollcommand'] = self.c.frameBottom.textBoxYScroll.set

        self.c.frameBottom.textBoxXScroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.c.frameBottom, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                                                         command=self.c.frameBottom.textBox.xview)
        self.c.frameBottom.textBox['xscrollcommand'] = self.c.frameBottom.textBoxXScroll.set
        # ------------------------------------------------
        # Create widgets for frameRight
        # ------------------------------------------------
        self.c.frameRight.btnStatus = tk.Button(self.c.frameRight, text='Status Window', command=self.launchWinStatus)
        self.c.frameRight.btnSpare1 = tk.Button(self.c.frameRight, text='Send Middle', command=self.btnSpare1)
        self.c.frameRight.btnSpare2 = tk.Button(self.c.frameRight, text='Spare 2', command=self.btnSpare2)

        # ------------------------------------------------

        # ------------------------------------------------
        # Layout widgets in frameTop
        # ------------------------------------------------
        self.c.frameTop.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.c.frameTop.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=0)
        self.c.frameTop.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.c.frameTop.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=0)

        self.c.frameTop.textBox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.c.frameTop.textBoxYScroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.c.frameTop.textBoxXScroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        # ------------------------------------------------
        # Layout widgets in frameMiddle
        # ------------------------------------------------
        self.c.frameMiddle.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.c.frameMiddle.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=0)
        self.c.frameMiddle.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.c.frameMiddle.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=0)

        self.c.frameMiddle.textBox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.c.frameMiddle.textBoxYScroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.c.frameMiddle.textBoxXScroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        # ------------------------------------------------
        # Layout widgets in frameBottom
        # ------------------------------------------------
        self.c.frameBottom.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.c.frameBottom.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=0)
        self.c.frameBottom.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.c.frameBottom.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=0)

        self.c.frameBottom.textBox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.c.frameBottom.textBoxYScroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.c.frameBottom.textBoxXScroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        # ------------------------------------------------
        # Layout widgets in frameRight
        # ------------------------------------------------
        self.c.frameRight.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.c.frameRight.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)

        self.c.frameRight.btnStatus.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.c.frameRight.btnSpare1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.c.frameRight.btnSpare2.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        # ------------------------------------------------
        # Layout frames in top container
        # ------------------------------------------------
        numOfCols = 2
        numOfRows = 6

        self.c.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, pad=3)
        self.c.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=0, pad=3)

        self.c.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1, pad=3)
        self.c.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1, pad=3)
        self.c.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1, pad=3)
        self.c.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1, pad=3)
        self.c.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1, pad=3)
        self.c.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1, pad=3)

        frameTopRowCol = [0, 0]
        frameTopSpan = [2, 1]

        frameMiddleRowCol = [frameTopRowCol[0] + frameTopSpan[0],
                             frameTopRowCol[1]]
        frameMiddleSpanRC = [2, 1]

        frameBottomRowCol = [frameMiddleRowCol[0] + frameMiddleSpanRC[0],
                             frameMiddleRowCol[1]]
        frameBottomSpanRC = [2, 1]

        frameRightRowCol = [frameTopRowCol[0],
                            frameTopRowCol[1] + frameTopSpan[1]]
        frameRightSpanRC = [numOfRows, 1]

        self.c.frameTop.grid(row=frameTopRowCol[0], column=frameTopRowCol[1],
                             rowspan=frameTopSpan[0], columnspan=frameTopSpan[1], sticky="nsew")
        self.c.frameMiddle.grid(row=frameMiddleRowCol[0], column=frameMiddleRowCol[1],
                                rowspan=frameMiddleSpanRC[0], columnspan=frameMiddleSpanRC[1], sticky="nsew")
        self.c.frameBottom.grid(row=frameBottomRowCol[0], column=frameBottomRowCol[1],
                                rowspan=frameBottomSpanRC[0], columnspan=frameBottomSpanRC[1], sticky="nsew")
        self.c.frameRight.grid(row=frameRightRowCol[0], column=frameRightRowCol[1],
                               rowspan=frameRightSpanRC[0], columnspan=frameRightSpanRC[1], sticky="nsew")

        # ------------------------------------------------
        # Layout top container in window
        # ------------------------------------------------
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, pad=3)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1, pad=3)

        # ------------------------------------------------
        # Layout window
        # ------------------------------------------------
        top.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, pad=3)
        top.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1, pad=3)

    def menuOptionsOpen(self):
        print("menuOptionsOpen")

    def menuOptionsClose(self):
        print("menuOptionsClose")

    def menuHelpAbout(self):
        print("menuHelpAbout")

    def launchWinStatus(self):
        print ("launchWinStatus")

    def btnSpare1(self):
        print("btnSpare1")

    def btnSpare2(self):
        print("btnSpare2")

    def upDateGui(self):
        print("upDateGui")

        # Perform update every x milliseconds
        self.after(1000, self.upDateGui)

# Main
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = WinMain(root)
    root.mainloop()

# Launch Main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have a section at line 174 where I can change rowconfigure weights and this has peculiar effects that I can't explain.  It should be able to fix the height of some rows while other rows are allowed to grow/shrink with the window down to a minimum size.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things:

There is a lot of code not relevant to the problem.

You have constructed a confusing widget hierarchy. The class WinMain() 
is instantiated with root as master. While `WinMain()` inherits `Frame()`, 
you never put any widgets inside self. Then you create the name `top = self.winfo_toplevel()` which is the running `Tk()` instance = `root` = `master` = `self.master` = `self.c`.

Your use of notation is confusing;

```
self.c.frameTop.textBox = tk.Text(self.c.frameTop, ...
```

Why save reference to the Text widget in the textBox attribute of frameTop?

Finally you configure grid in `self` (Frame which does not contain anything) 
and `root`.

I think much of your problems are because you have confused the names of things. I'm providing an example below with only the necessary code to get the correct behaviour. My use of bg colors is to ease identification of the different widgets.

```
import tkinter as tk

# Main Window
class WinMain(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.config(bg='tan')
        master.geometry('600x400+800+50')
        self.pack(padx=10, pady=10, expand=True, fill='both')
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)     # Expand cols 0 & 2 with resize

        # Top
        frameTop = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Top", bg='peru')
        frameTop.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        frameTop.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)   # Expand frame with resize
        frameTop.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        Top_Box = tk.Text(frameTop, borderwidth=3, relief=tk.SUNKEN, width=20, height=2)
        Top_Box.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)

        # Middle
        frameMiddle = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Middle", padx=5, pady=5, bg='tomato')
        frameMiddle.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        frameMiddle.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)   # Expand frame with resize
        frameMiddle.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        Middle_Box = tk.Text(frameMiddle, borderwidth=3, relief=tk.SUNKEN, width=20, height=2)
        Middle_Box.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)

        # Bottom
        frameBottom = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Bottom", padx=5, pady=5, bg='khaki')
        frameBottom.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        frameBottom.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)   # Expand frame with resize
        frameBottom.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        Bottom_Box = tk.Text(frameBottom, borderwidth=3, relief=tk.SUNKEN, width=20, height=2)
        Bottom_Box.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)

        # Right
        frameRight = tk.Frame(self, borderwidth=5, relief=tk.GROOVE, bg='thistle')
        frameRight.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=3, sticky='nsew')
        btnStatus = tk.Button(frameRight, text='Status Window',)
        btnSpare1 = tk.Button(frameRight, text='Send Middle')
        btnSpare2 = tk.Button(frameRight, text='Spare 2')
        btnStatus.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
        btnSpare1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
        btnSpare2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="ew")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = WinMain(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me so soon. I am not able to try your solution at the moment but when I do I’ll let you know how I got on

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  With your help I managed to get my GUI to perform as expected.  I need the self. references to my widgets so that other class functions can access them.  At first I left out the widths and heights on the text boxes and the GUI still did not scale as I like but after adding these parameters it worked fine .  Thanks again. @figbeam